# How to identify if class has implemented marker interface

Tags: java

I received this question during interview, the question is

> How to identify if class has implemented marker interface

If there is a way to find, how to know which marker interface is implemented

Comment: Why minus it was a interview question which I like to clarify. Does it make sense to minus

Comment: You are not showing any signs of prior research. The idea is that we always help you "getting one step further" - assuming that you tried to make the first steps yourself. Dropping a question here "explain to me please" does not count as "prior research".

Comment: @GhostCat I tried finding solution in google but I didn't found any solution, at end option left in stackoverflow Community. 
May be I didn't put too much of research on this topic.

Comment: Never mind. One thing with prior research is: if you can't think of good words to search for, one might do some searching and conclude "i cant find anything". But: especially when you are newbie, and a newbie to Java, most questions you can think of ... have been asked here. So chances are always that you just have to search a bit longer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Class#getInterfaces()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()):

> Determines the interfaces implemented by the class or interface
>   represented by this object.
>
> If this object represents a class, the return value is an array
>   containing objects representing all interfaces implemented by the
>   class. The order of the interface objects in the array corresponds to
>   the order of the interface names in the implements clause of the
>   declaration of the class represented by this object. For example,
>   given the declaration:
>
> ```
> class Shimmer implements FloorWax, DessertTopping { ... }
> ```
>
> suppose the value of s is an instance of Shimmer; the value of the
>   expression:
>
> ```
> s.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]
> ```
>
> is the Class object that represents interface FloorWax; and the value
>   of:
>
> ```
> s.getClass().getInterfaces()[1]
> ```
>
> is the Class object that represents interface DessertTopping.

Note however that this approach will not return true for the scenario where instead a superclass of `Shimmer` implements the interfaces, for example as below:

```
public interface FloorWax { }

public interface DesertTopping { }

public class Shimmer implements implements FloorWax, DessertTopping { }

public class ShimmerChild extends Shimmer {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException
    System.out.println(new ShimmerChild().getClass().getInterfaces()[0]);
}
```

In a case where you would want for the below to return the interfaces, use the approach as described in @DylanMeeus answer with [Class#isAssignableFrom()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

Comment: Note: although correct, this is only part of the truth. This approach won't tell you about interfaces implemented by super classes of the object you are looking into (so I think).

Comment: @GhostCat Oh, interesting. I will have to test that out.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but its your answer; and your reputation; so its in your interest to look into that ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Indeed, you are correct. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using something like

`if(MarkerInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(otherClass.class))`

Imagine you have an interface named `MarkerInterface` and a class `OtherClass implements MarkerInterface`.

You could run something like this in main

```
if(MarkerInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(OtherClass.class))
{
   System.out.println("Otherclass uses the MarkerInterface");
}
```